# Fail to write publish settings to "filename.publish.xml". Please make sure file is writable

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api

[Click here for Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdRke.png)

First time publishing to a server

I am trying to publish a webforms website to my test server and this is the error I get.
Anyone know a fix or an alternative way to get the website pushed to my server? Website runs fine.

Comment: Just grant modify permissions to the specific folder to user IUSR.

Comment: @kami Just tried that and I still have the same error.

Comment: Did you try to grant permission to the IIS_IUSRS group and NETWORK SERVICE?

Comment: @kami I tried it a different way. I clicked on "show all files" clicked on the xlm file, right click and clicked " include in project" and then check out for edit in tfs. This makes its writable I guess  and I do not get that write error anymore. I am now encountering a server filepath publishing error but I will work through that. thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to give permissions on the folder level.

Answer (score 1):

I clicked on "show all files" clicked on the xlm file, right click and clicked " include in project" and then check out for edit in tfs.